# policy on "how do I draw this?" questions

Tags: discussion, questions, please-do-this-for-me

There are several, I think unnecessary, questions of the form "How can I draw this?" or "How can I draw this in TikZ?"

These add nothing to the site really. Sometimes there is some feature of the drawing that requires a library or some trickery and it could be rephrased. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22948/215) however, doesn't seem to have any merit...

Can we formulate a policy on how to deal with these questions? Close as not a real question?

Comment: The question should be phrased much better. I don't mind if he asked about waved arrows. However, it's still a RTFM type of question. (RTFM = Read The Fine Manual)

Comment: seems like an example of "gimme teh codez" on Stack Overflow: a simple request for someone else to do *all* the work for you :p

Comment: @Jeff I would love that as a "close" option: "closed for being 'gimme teh codez'"

Comment: The problem is that someone will always just go and draw the picture for them, regardless of whether there are comments telling the person asking the question to show what they have done, or what the problem is, etc.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I suggest:

- Support the OP in rephrasing the question by posting constructive comments
- Provide an answer with general advice how he can produce the drawing himself, such as recommending packages, tools or libraries
- Suggest creating detailed follow-up questions, if necessary
- If the question remains too vague, vote to close it as not a real question or too localized, depending on what fits better.

Rember accompanying closing votes by explaining comments, and let's be lenient towards new members.