# How do I draw this.....?

Tags: discussion, please-do-this-for-me

I know this question has been raised before at [policy on "how do I draw this?" questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1538/22413). I know a lot of us are annoyed by these questions. But I'm not so sure, as in the linked discussion, that these sorts of questions add nothing to the site. I believe they could add something if we had an appropriate tag, such as `[how-to-draw]`, or we came up with better titles that might help others doing a search for such things. A tag additionally could then be a place to first direct people to look to see *possibly similar* figures that they wish to duplicate.

I feel that the learning curve for either TikZ or PSTricks is steep enough that people can generally be quite lost about how to do even the simplest things. I discovered PSTricks many years ago and got to be quite comfortable with it. I began using TikZ about the time I joined this site.  Though there are similarities, much is different. For example, I feel, TikZ requires a much deeper understanding of LaTeX's macro expansion process than PSTricks requires.
And, for those people who are new to LaTeX and haven't used any of the graphical packages, I think they can feel quite overwhelmed and lost. Some of the answers/comments to TikZ questions are just rather off-putting, like comments that read "it's in the manual". Yes, that may be true, but the manuals are very long or broken across many different documents; finding what you want to do can be extremely challenging.

I've been thinking about this policy of ours for a while. And it seems that increasingly we're becoming less *friendly* toward people who may just be totally out to sea about how to even start something.
Recently I was downvoted for [answering such a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241587/22413)---and, I am **not** complaining about that; I understand the reason---but, that's prompted me to actually go ahead and post this.

Some of us actually enjoy trying to answer such *how to draw* questions: sometimes just because it challenges our own understanding of TikZ/PSTricks; other times just because it's fun to create the image. New people are always going to come to our site and post these sorts of annoying questions no matter how much we try to discourage it. I generally only answer such question for people with low rep. counts, which I take to be a sign that they may also be novice LaTeX (and family) users.

I'm actually much more bothered by the repeated downvotes for the OP. I feel it casts us in a negative light when so much of what we do it supportive. I don't think it necessary that we view the people posting these questions as *vampires* (unless it's the same individually repeatedly posting time and time again the same sort of "do this for me" sort of question).

Could we come up with a policy that would make it more forgiving for OPs who may not even know where to start with TikZ/PSTricks? Could we please find a way not to be offended by these questions? After all, no one is saying, "Hey you there, *you* must answer my post!". They're just reaching out hoping that someone will answer them.

Comment: while in many ways i agree with your proposal, i remember a particular influx of "do this for me" questions that turned out to be homework problems.  and that is precisely the *wrong* situation in which to respond with a refined answer.  if some way can be found to help genuinely motivated beginners, without servicing parasites (and to reliably distinguish between the two categories), i'd be in favor.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Excellent point.  I had not thought of the issue of a TeX document being a graded assessment/homework in the sense that it's the document preparation and creation that's being graded.  Perhaps then, we should consider formulating guiding lines about what's helpful and what goes too far?

Comment: The [poster](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/56814/fffff) had already gotten the lection on MWEs on [his first question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188695/5763) but the usual crowd fed him and so he learned nothing. Now he probably also has learned nothing.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Maybe I should be looking at previous posts then....  You're probably right about him/her not learning anything.  But still for him as a newbie I feel a soft spot for the challenge of learning these things.  At any rate, I'm still mulling this over in my head.  On the one hand, I'm definitely bothered by those who seem to put little effort in to their question; on the other, I sometimes feel they might be totally at a loss for how to start.

Comment: The problem with some of the 'draw this for me' questions is that they are very hard to see as generic: it's often not clear what part the user is struggling with for a 'fair' edit.

Comment: The main problem is probably that it is not really *TeX*-related... The problem in most questions is "how does this drawing maps to mathematics*, and whether one uses *TikZ* or - excuse me - Inkscape is irrelevant to some extent. Perhaps one should think about creating a StackExchange for TeX drawing challenges...

Comment: @CommuSoft I use a lot of `TikZ` in my documents.  It integrates well for the sorts of things I need to do in my documents.  Most of my questions about `TikZ` are LaTeX related:  but before you can even get down to that level, you need to know how to build things in TikZ.  Fully implemented in LaTeX (unlike pstricks which relies on postscript), questions about how to make a diagram with TikZ is a LaTeX question for me.  We all have to start somewhere.

Comment: @CommuSoft But despite what I just said in the previous comment, I have often wondered about what you've suggested here:  should there be a separate site here dedicated solely to something like `TikZ` or `pstricks`?

Comment: @JosephWright It would be nice if there were a way to classify answers:  something similar to tags that could enumerate the methods used.

Comment: A low rep count is not, I think, a good basis for deciding whether to answer or how to answer. There have been some users who've asked a series of these questions and have low rep because their previous questions have been down-voted for similar reasons. I think you would have to use low rep as a reason to look at the user's history of posting and then decide. I certainly did not down-vote your answer, but I had looked at the user's previous question which was essentially identical but with a different diagram.

Comment: Could we instead ask users to simplify the diagram they are asking for? Often, users ask a series of how-to-draw questions about relatively complex images. What they get in return is a magic spell which compiles to produce the diagram. In a way, this is inevitable: creating the diagram is quite a bit of work so spelling out how to go about it would be much too long for an answer. If users could be encouraged to break their own diagrams down into simpler steps, answers could more reasonably be expected to explain code. Also, breaking a diagram into steps is the first thing needed to draw it.

Comment: You wrote *unless it's the same individually repeatedly posting time and time again the same sort of "do this for me" sort of question*. I think that of course it is not the same individual, but it does not matter. While speculating about the effects how that might seem to the outside world, the idea of getting nice graphics from here might spread and soon, who knows what kind of queue of "draw this for me"-requests will we be presented with.

Comment: I have a more or less related question. Since I had this thought from time to time: **why exactly do we have such a high stake in the site's reputation?**. E.g. someone might say "TeX.sx is such a nerdy and annoying site, you do not get any help from there unless you basically write the whole code yourself. Weirdos.". So? :) While I kind of applaud the likes of Harish Kumar and you (A.Ellett) for being so helpful, I lean towards showing a clear line of what we deem inappropriate.

Comment: @henry Who are *we* exactly in your final sentence? Who put us in charge? Are we paying the server bills? I want to close half of the TikZ questions if it was to my liking. And I have the means, the yellow badge etc. But it is not our call. Hanging out here doesn't give you a share of Stackexchange network. It only means you like spending time here. Nothing else. Regarding the site reputation; we have spent so much time and effort with having great fun in return. I will be bothered a lot if we screw up because some nerds try to be correct and bully new users.

Comment: @percusse Of course you are right with everything you say. And in a way, I am suggesting that the mods stand up and say, "yes, we strongly urge you users, to not react to those "poor quality" questions. Please do not."  But whether one actually does reply or not, is up to to her-/himself of course. Alright, so I realize that you have a lot of this heard already but I think it is fair to say that this is not bullying. So I find the text building blocks are nicely phrased and when I have the time&will, I use them.

Comment: @percusse I am strongly against bullying. I myself have experienced some passive aggressive comments on here but... so be it. AFAIK, at some point users with toxic behavior either leave or turn around. YMMV.

Comment: @percusse About that "share of Stackexchange" angle. I did not mean this. Yes, we cannot and should not dictate something. But I feel that we should be allowed to  to point users in the right way. The way this issue is heading is that establishes a reputation as if people can post these requests on here and you get your wish fulfilled. Imho, I think this is not a good token of this site. But again, I am only speaking for myself and I can only ask others to not "serve" these requests. Finally: what would we lose if these new accounts stop requesting TikZ graphics?

Comment: @henry Perfectly true. If it stays as *pointing* but not *do as we command, we don't like strangers here new user*. Moreover, I sometimes (rarely though) like answering these questions. The main question is why do we care ? It can stay open an unattended. Got past front page, nobody would even notice them other than our OCD reviewers and closers.

Comment: Spot on. They're my favourite kind of question anyway. I never let an ugly question take the shine off a beautiful answer.

Answer (score 26):

I also discussed this before: [Our Do-it-for-me and Draw-it-for-me comments don't reflect our hypocrisy. Can they be improved?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4267/our-do-it-for-me-and-draw-it-for-me-comments-dont-reflect-our-hypocrisy-can-th) and I was under the impression that it was settled. But things have changed since then. Our recent residents are getting really hostile more frequently. There is no other way of putting it. Especially in the chat room I'm witnessing a lot of *ah, look at this idiot* type of comments on questions and especially drawing attention to a flaming commentary to show off how right they are. And I am actually waiting for the 100th monkey<sup>1</sup> to pick up this nasty behavior and change the color of the spirit here which is happening for some time now.

Maybe we should remind ourselves that this is only TeX we are dealing with. An obscure typesetting system for mostly academic purposes, not a cure for cancer. It is fun and beautiful nothing else. So non-TeX people have all the rights not knowing it. And it looks ridiculous and funny when users occasionally come to this site to ask something and see this small print popping under questions with serious attitude telling to do *yada yada yada*. There is a difference between letting someone know about the style and registering them to your own club.

I don't find this pretentious *oh let's teach him how to fish* attitude comfortable. Because if you really want to teach (I don't know where this self-confidence comes from too) you try to be nice, you don't prove how correct you are. If there is a duplicate close it. If there is none let them be. We have more than enough means to deal with unanswered questions.

**Housekeeping does not equate to repelling boring questions.**

There will always be boring questions. But of course if you feel like TeX-SX is your daily dosage of SuDoKu and you don't like your fun being spoiled by users who are not supplying enough fun, then you get grumpy and belittle questions.

Being an old user or hi-rep doesn't give anyone the right to be the discipline police. Especially some users are quite annoying to be the first one to engage with some new users, piss them off right off the bat and move to the next question where they can fix lacking manners of another user with a hearty Welcome to TeX-SX and then following with **here are the ways you fail: code blocks, thank yous, MWEs, usernames**. I have been tangentially involved in some of those code block compositions. Nobody back then thought that it would be a tool for the etiquette police.

In the meantime, often times a potential answerer has to deal with a overzealous response of the OP leading to *read my question properly* type of response because someone pissed that user off before we can finish reading the question.

Here are recent three questions that are too broad (asks specifically a certain plot type) and unclear (really? with two downvotes) and the last one is also interesting because OP said something but failed to make the code work (!?). Just go through review queue there are lots of examples.

[Syntax/Railroad diagrams in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244450/syntax-railroad-diagrams-in-latex)

[How to make a Minkowski Diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244472/how-to-make-a-minkowski-diagram)

[Text Bold with fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244325/text-bold-with-fontspec)

Yes, we are very friendly indeed. There you go, evidence you wish evidence you find in there, tons of them.

---

If you had the privilege to hang out in Math.Stackexchange you know exactly what I mean above (which is still apparently triggering *Oh, I don't see that happening* type of turn-the-other-cheek behavior among us). I'm hoping that you won't classify MSE as a user-friendly place. However, amazingly, [here is a blog post](http://math.blogoverflow.com/2015/05/10/growth-statistics-on-math-se/) showing precisely what is going to happen which I tried to hand-wave above.

The icing-on-cake part is in the comments, I hope it rings a bell. Because I'm out of arguments if you still cannot see. Apparently my crystal ball is pretty shiny.

---

<sup>1</sup> : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundredth_monkey_effect

Comment: ...a good read!

Comment: As a person who asks `TikZ` questions, I highly appreciate answers along the lines of _teach him how to fish_. If I don't understand the code in the answer given, I won't be able to use it again for similar purposes in the future. As an example, I once received a [good solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139726/9077) to a problem I posed, but the code was (to me) so complicated that I failed to understand it. When I tried to ask for explanations of the code, I was told to "read the LaTeX2e reference manual". Needless to say, I've never used that code since.

Comment: @Sverre *How to fish* context here, is not giving terse or extremely concise answers. It is rather answering a question before OP reformulates their question hence learns how to ask properly for the next time.

Comment: @Sverre I actually read a good chunk of the reference manual. It's short and clear on most points. So I'd argue it's fair to suggest reading it. For it's a good suggestion. Since it exists on websites, just use FIND in your browser on a page that mirrors it. No need to even download it.

Comment: @percusse I'm not sure I got the point of your post. Are you for answering questions regardless if they have code/other info apart from an image and a request to draw it? Or are you for with some conditions? Sorry, I got both vibes from your answer. :D

Comment: @Alenanno I answer everything if I'm in the mood, otherwise I don't engage rather than preaching the religion of TeX-SX monk practice via autocomment blocks. Because somebody else might be in the mood and might write an answer. Check the text block I offered in the linked meta question on top of my answer.

Comment: @percusse That made me smile, but maybe it's a bit too informal? :D

Comment: @Alenanno Who said this is a formal encounter? We are actually using for a year already.

Comment: @percusse Ah, I haven't seen it being used.

Comment: Can you extend a bit on the latest edit concerning the MSE stuff?

Comment: I feel this is related to overall community behaviour, not limited to the *Do it for me stuff*. Maybe you can even open a completely new topic?

Comment: @Johannes_B What is MSE?

Comment: @A.Ellett Math.Stackexchange

Comment: @percusse by the way, i want to apologize if my comments came of as hostile, they were surely not meant to be. I bet you know that you could have addressed the issue personally. :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B I would have if it was a personal issue.

Comment: @Johannes_B I don't see any evidence of hostility in your comments. I don't see anything unfriendly in 2 out of 3 of those questions. In the third, I see one comment which might come across as unfriendly although I don't see any evidence for thinking it ill-motivated or hostile.

Comment: @cfr Ask a question and I'll close it after 10 minutes. Then we talk again. In the second one the question is closed after I answered. That's just nonsense. The first is also pretty clear. Again nonsense. The third one you answered yourself. Do we have to swear to the users to be rude?

Comment: I meant the comments. I thought that's what you were talking about. Not that it matters, but I didn't answer any of them.

Comment: I have thought a lot about all this within the last few days. You mentioned classical forums, and if you are serious about leaving TeX.SX, i very much welcome you to join [LaTeX-Community](http://latex-community.org/forum/). There is currently one active moderator and the admin who are regularely answer stuff. About a handful of users drops in once in a while. We could really use somebody with high knowledge answering questions, as i simply cannot manage it all by myselve. No need to rush there, no voting, no reviewing system, no predefined stock comments.

Comment: The system annoyed me a few times when discussion took place in the comments, just to clarify the question and the user needs. No, all will be said within two more comments, i don't want to drag this to chat. If a question requires *How do you want this? Should that be above or below?* and other details up to explaining how to open a terminal, an innovative and so-called efficient Q/A site is just not the right place. My opinion. But all you guys hang around here for rep or something and leave me alone up there, where still traffic is. Wanna answer questions? Get over there and help out.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mean you. I got a bit mad about all this idiotic faffing about rules.

Comment: @johannes no problem at all. I gave up already

Comment: What i have wrote in the linked post nearly broke my heart knowing all the traffic and knowledge around here. http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=90007#p90007 I cannot say get over at TeX.SX, a site in a multi-million commercial network. Once i start that, the forum will die completely. Also related: http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2015/02/latex-beginners-guide-ebook-for-free/

Comment: @Johannes_B I got pinged for this. Is it for me ? Because I couldn't put it in any context.

Comment: @percusse Yes, that was indeed for you. I hoped you decide to join LC and answer some questions. :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B I was there for a while actually http://latex-community.org/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=55652 but didn't stick around.

Comment: (+1) @percusse, beautiful answer. I have a lot of stuff to say regarding this matter but the comment section is not suitable for this. When I was an absolute beginner in Latex in 2011 when my supervisor has told me to type my thesis in Latex, I was horrified because it is difficult in comparison with Microsoft Word and it takes too much time to learn it. This place was my only hope to seek answers. I saw the beauty of Latex via answers in here and because of that I became loyal to it. To be Cont.

Comment: ^ Cont. I'm always against the policy of closing answers when it comes to beginners unless if there is a serious problem with the post.  Unfortunately, some Latex profs in here pretend that Latex is friendly BUT it is not. It is difficult to master in short time. Another excuse by some profs in here is the homeworkophobia, so to speak. No one care if you type your homework in Word or Latex and I doubt that in undergrad/grad curricula there is a course regarding Latex, at least not in engineering.

Answer (score 19):

I don't like this type of question but not because of the "do-it-for-me" -- after all most questions are "do-it-for-me" questions. The problem is that the question is "cheap", in German I would say "hingerotzt". The OP didn't put any effort in it. There is no information about the system he/she used and for what the graphic is needed. No context or anything, only a picture. Even the name of the user is cheap.

Such questions try to get the maximum with minimum costs, and this imho is disrespectful towards all the generous people who spent their time to answer questions. I feel exploited by such questions. I want to see in questions at least an indication that the asker is aware that they address persons with a free will to ignore the question and not some slaves or machines bound to answer. A minimal example or some context may not always needed but neither is the tip in a restaurant.

Comment: It doesn't apply to me. And I have the utmost respect to you and also many others here. However; let me put this out in the open so that it is not implied continuously as a self-fulfilled prophecy. I'm not helping people. There is no getting benefit or making poor souls happier type of feeling. We are not a charity foundation. I completely and solely hung out here because I like getting TeX results in short amount of time for my own fun. It might be sometimes generous of me but I cannot expect anything in return. Doing so would make me someone I hope I'm not.

Comment: There is no respectfulness involved in any of this. Maybe this is the point that the more we make people satisfied the more we assume that we are owed something. I don't. Tomorrow, the whole thing goes down and I would keep doing this somewhere else. I think TeX-SX problem is that knowledgeable people feel superior to the less TeXnicians. I think that is a very very wrong.  We shouldn't confuse TeXpertise with ownership of the website. This is a public domain. Anybody can do whatever they want. If they ask shitty questions, if they try to getaway with little effort, so be it.

Comment: They do or don't get an answer. It is up to other procrastinators. We don't get to be the moral compass of internet. That is a fight that we would surely loose.

Comment: @percusse: I'm here for the fun too. But there is no fun in answering questions of low qualitity. It is also no fun, when the ratio of bad questions increase over some level. So I'm pursuying my interests when I demand good quality questions.  I know quite well that the askers have other interests, and I'm willing to take this into account but not if I get the impression that they ignore my interests completly.

Comment: I wish I could have come up with your last sentence. Very well put. That is something I forgot completely to mention that no matter how technical things are this is still a social interaction in essence. Hence, all the social norms apply. I totally get your frustration however, I can't help but emphasize that some half-baked weird system of reviews and rules should not guide us to decide how we proceed with our social engagement with this site.

Comment: @percusse: I'm not frustrated. A bad question doesn't throw me in a depression. There are bad questions, they are "cheap" questions. I spent some time to nudge people to improve them to keep the level of bad questions low and the rest I ignore.

Comment: you just described capitalism "get the maximum with minimum costs"!

Comment: @Leeser: No, I described an egoist and selfcentered position. Capitalism and empathy for the need of other people are no contradiction.

Comment: Another random user chiming in: Miss Fischer's reply sums it up in the best way for me. I just do not get any motivation whatsoever to involve myself and dedicate my time to these type of questions. About the "2 classes" between users, I have been ignorant of that thus far. Besides, I have only experienced a kind attitude on here and any "conspiring" (for the lack of a better word) by users in the chat... good for them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Frustration was unnecessarily strong. My bad. I meant something along the lines of nuisance.

Comment: A thousand times yes! I wholeheartedly agree with Ulrike's answer.

Answer (score 14):

I was going to post this as a response to @UlrikeFischer.  But then I realized I was saying something more than just a response, so I decided to make this one more idea to enter as an answer as part of this discussion.

Much like in math, when a new field of inquiry opens up, the initial results are relatively quick and easy to solve; as the field develops the results become harder to find and solve, and require ever deeper levels of mastery (and/or cunning).

Similarly, here on TeX-SX, many of the easy questions have been asked and answered.  That's not to say such easy questions are still not laying around waiting to be asked.  But, for the interested learner of LaTeX (and family), most questions they might come up with have likely already be posted and answered.  And thanks to some of the giants on this site, we have some very thorough and elucidating answers (or comments).

Certainly as new packages get developed and attract new users, those rudimentary questions will open up once more.  But meanwhile, the questions either become rather abstruse and rarefied, or they are the questions of those---most likely---completely at a loss of where to start.

Personally, I would like to see two developments on this site.  One is to develop a repository of well presented solutions to common typographical features: among which would be the creation of diagrams and charts using TikZ, pstricks, Metapost, etc. (more on this in the paragraphs below).  The second development is really outside of the scope of the posted question; nevertheless, I'll mention it: a collection of questions and answers on best practices (yes, I know this will result in a lot of opinions, but still I think those could be useful to learners).

Here's one approach I've been thinking of regarding the development of such repositories inspired a bit by @cfr 's comment to my original post.

cfr suggests that the user simplify the diagram or pair down the question.  I think this is a great idea.  But also, I think some of these posters might just turn around and say, "I don't know how to start any of this."  My suggestion is not to make the OP simplify the diagram.  Instead, we, as the more seasoned users of this site and more seasoned users of the tools, could create new questions and post answers that breakdown the OP's original question into stages.  On the one hand, this creates a bit of work.  On the other, it allows us to structure things in a way that is better organized and searchable than a newbie might know how to do.

For example, take the following question [Draw a picture where some parts are tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241917/22413).  It can be broken down into various parts.  The tables on the left hand side could be structured in TikZ as split rectangles.  The table in the center could import a tabular environment into the picture for which there is already a [good answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9254/22413) though I'd like to see a way of doing it as a TikZ matrix or a *two-way* split rectangle(??).  The right hand side could just be viewed as drawing connectors between the node:  a rather rudimentary level sort of thing to do in TikZ or pstricks, but I don't think we have anything illustrating plainly how to do this except buried in other questions and therefore not readily searchable.

My suggestion is that a solution be posted for each of these aspects of the picture.  While we do have some questions about working with split nodes, we don't really have a question which is "how do I draw a split node?" So, we in-the-know could post such a question (perhaps as a community wiki).  Then we could answer our own question illustrating the technique (again perhaps as a community wiki).  But then this would also allow others to come in and showcase how to do the similar technique in pstricks of Metapost.  Then we could go back to the OP's question and in the comments (or in a solution) link to the new posting or show how to integrate the various ideas.    In fact, my own question about [Setting a length with a key to a TikZ node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241964/22413) came up in an initial foray into answering the question about drawing the diagram mentioned at the start of the previous paragraph (I haven't posted anything yet about this because I just haven't had that sort of procrastination time available).  In this manner we would gradually build up respositories of techniques.  (Right now I can recall seeing many cool things done with TikZ, but then the question is how do I find it 9 months later and when I finally have a project where the cool thing would be useful.  Afterall, the original question could have been about something rather tangential to whatever coolness might have been there.)

I know this can be a lot of work.  It could get a bit haphazard too.  But I think it might offer a solution to how to make these "draw this picture for me" into something more general and useful to current and future users of the site.

Comment: this kind of addresses the problem that it is often difficult to find the question that one knows is a "duplicate".  adhering to the q/a format does make that difficult when a question is phrased in a manner only vaguely related to the appropriate answer, and sometimes the tagging doesn't help much either.  i hesitate to change the phrasing of a question to something that looks entirely unrelated (although i don't hesitate to correct the spelling of a command or package name).  so coming up with lucid questions could perhaps be a goal for a community wiki meta question?

Comment: Some of the *original* questions, that new ones get closed as duplicates of, sometimes have answers that must be *cruel* to a newcomer looking for a solution. Some give a solution in form of a one liner, no explanation at all. On the other hand it seems that reading background information has become a little off-trend. Some answers are more extensive, but addressing multiple topics and it is hard to really find the matching line to the problem at hand.

Comment: Some of the FAQs we get have nice answers and get updated once in a while, for example the *yes, you need to run bibtex/biber.* business that gets in every day. For other stuff, there is no real *quality control*. If an answer is hidden in plain sight, it is still hidden. I think we should somehow rework our stock answers. All of my thoughts are not related to the *drawThisForMeBusiness*, of course, but i think it is relevant to mention this.

Comment: I think there are good ideas here. I still think that we need to encourage users to break diagrams down into simpler steps. If they have no idea where to start, then then could ask about *that* i.e. 'I want to draw this diagram. How can I break the project down into manageable steps?' But there is a huge temptation for people to respond with code for the diagram. And that is not, I think, helpful. The problem is not just the one @Johannes_B mentions: many answers to newcomers' questions themselves strike me as cruel.

Comment: @cfr You cannot pre-intervent. Somebody is looking to draw a log of wood, which frankly is a brown cylinder. Summing up, we have a question for a log of wood, a thermos, a rocket and a beer can, all could be breaken down to cylinders. And if somebody tells you the answer is hidden in *how to draw a can of beer* it might be confusing/misleading/frustrating.

Comment: @Johannes_B Sorry. I don't understand what you said. ('pre-intervent'?) And I agree about the hiddenness. Did I say something which you thought meant I disagreed?

Comment: @cfr You want to encourage a new user to break down the question to simpler stuff, i.e. draw a circle, a cube, a pumpkin .... But as soon as the user posts a question, the *do it for me* part is done. You could set up a page *before you answer, read this ...* but we all know that it ain't gotta work.

Comment: @Johannes_B It depends what you mean by 'work'. Do I think it will stop the draw-it-for-me questions? Of course not. Do I think it might be more helpful to *some* users than magic spells? Yes. But that is a heavily qualified claim. My point is that *if* a user wants to know how to construct a diagram, posting a magic spell is not going to help. I think that some users do want this, but certainly not all. So I think it might reduce serial-draw-it-for-mes somewhat, but I'm certainly not suggesting that it will end them. (And it won't do anything about draw-it-for-me *first* posts.)

Comment: @cfr You are right. One german comedian, who also seems to have a medical degree, had something  in his program. *I'll give you ten dollars, you are quite happy for a few minutes. Later that day, you loose exactly this bill, you will be angry for days.* Tha's a bit of human behaviour in our selves. A *draw this for me* question has a higher negative weight, than one single well-done question could balance. Stupid humans ;-)

Answer (score 8):

I agree with Ulrike in her perspective.

The problems I've noticed are various. I understand that being polite is good and I often try to word the (few) comments I post in a neutral manner. And I'm also lenient to new users (especially completely new ones). But being polite and lenient doesn't mean and/or justify feeding the vampires.

While I really love Tikz, *really*, I think that answering the "gimme teh codez" questions is not only not helpful to the OP (in the long term), but it's also harmful to the site in the way that we are simply a free workforce for people too lazy to even describe their problem, let alone post some code attempt.

I don't demand that the code being posted works excellently, but I appreciate that there is an effort. It also depends on the case, I've answered questions without codes where I thought it was appropriate. Maybe I'm even wrong in those cases, but it was my call. And indeed, it's not even a "is there a code in it?" problem. It's more of a "do I think this user attempted to look into it before asking?" which is often not the case.

And it often happens that when I'm looking for how to answer a "draw it for me" question (for my own curiosity), I stumble upon very related and sometimes exact duplicates of the same question. This means that the OP didn't even take the time to google the general problem, let alone dig into the code.

By the way, I don't find these questions to be boring. Any Tikz-related question is fun for me (and often I resist the urge to just post an answer). What I don't appreciate is the thought that I'm *almost supposed* to give an answer when the OP only posted an image with some "Any help is appreciated. Thanks." with no context, no effort whatsoever or even a slight mention of said effort.

Comment: @percusse When you see a very complicated Tikz graph that requires work with *no effort* to at least draw a node, and the OP doesn't care about learning but just to "give the code already", then that's a vampire. See also [The Help Vampire: A Spotter's Guide](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm). I don't think I'm being picky or pompous, I have said I like answering questions and I have to admit I'm a bit torn on this issue, but I prefer cooperating with someone than working for them. But I want to reiterate what I said above: It's not even "is there code" problem.

Comment: @Alenanno The problem with the "Vampire spotter's guide" is that it's about
judging what we cannot know.  We can't know whether the OP has
googled the question.  Perhaps the OP wasn't able to decipher the search results.
Perhaps you want the OP to state they googled and list what they found:
personally, I don't care what they googled and didn't find; I just want a
question.  "How do I draw this?" is a question.

Comment: @Alenanno Regarding duplicates: finding duplicates isn't particularly easy
even when you know the keywords to search on.  In many of these "How do I
draw this?" question, the OP may not know what to search for.  You
come from a position of epistemic privilege which means you are in a
better position to get more productive google search results.  For those
new to LaTeX (or even just TikZ or pstricks), such insight has yet to be gained.

Comment: @Alenanno Finally, there is an art to writing good questions.  Many of us lack this skill.  I can't tell you how many times I cringe when I reread some of the questions I've posted on this site.  They are clunky, or too long, or confusing.  But that may attest to my own confusion about what wasn't working in my code and my difficulty in understanding how to even frame the question.

Comment: @A.Ellett Yes, we can. Just mentioning what you searched and why it didn't help is good enough. I can't read minds, but I can read an explanation in a question. You say you don't care, but we're discussing about what constitutes a standard. Just asking "draw it for me" is not a standard I can agree with. Finally, writing a question is not always easy, I agree. But writing a badly formatted/written question that can be improved, is better than writing nothing, don't you agree?

Comment: @A.Ellett True, duplicates are hard to find, although not impossible, and I agree with you more on them, because it is indeed complicated. But I've seen many users that did search before posting. So maybe it's not that hard a task.

Comment: It's dialogue on this topic that I was looking for.  And I'm happy to see so much conversation back-and-forth on this.  You've contributed to this conversation, and I am grateful for that (even while I don't necessarily agree with all your points).  :-)

Comment: @A.Ellett This site has always been quite polite. It's one thing I like about it! :D

Comment: @percusse You're generalising my discourse a bit. I'm not blocking anyone's access and not everyone that doesn't add some code is an help vampire. I'm just saying that I'd like to see some cooperation when someone asks a question, cooperation that can be expressed in various ways. And indeed, like I said, it's not a black & white issue: not all questions without code are bad. It depends on the case.

Comment: @percusse I'm not, I was just expanding on it. Name one thing that contradicts what I said in the answer and I'll tell you why it doesn't.

Comment: @percusse I always said it depended on the case and it was not a question of code or not code. From my answer *"It also depends on the case, I've answered questions without codes where I thought it was appropriate."* By the way, today I've been working on a code for hours for a question without code. That goes to show that I don't see it as a B&W issue. I'm one of those 10 people you mention. Also, it doesn't help the discussion if you keep calling people pompous just because they (slightly) disagree with you.

Comment: Once somebody has decided that hostile motives, bad character and ill will explain what you do online, nothing you can say will convince them otherwise.  The accusations are effectively a wall which you cannot breach because everything you say will be understood in the light of those assumptions. At least, that has been my experience on TeX SE.  You [and I] are not among the TeX nobility and are not, therefore, entitled to respect. Not only can we not be assumed well-intentioned. Our intentions must be assumed evil. We are simply a rot to be eliminated. No suggestion of mere frustration here!

Comment: @percusse I know you didn't meant to attack me personally but defining my opinions defines me a bit as well. But anyway, no problem. :D  I don't see this fake superiority you're talking about. I'm just asking OPs to put some effort when it's possible. Yesterday [I answered a question without code whatsoever](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244438/4778) (it's also why I didn't answer sooner to your comment, apologies), and it goes to show that I don't feel superior to anybody. But if a question is a simple shape with some additions, it's nice to see that the OP *at least* drew the simple shape.

Comment: @cfr Were you agreeing with me? Sorry I'm 90% sure but... :P

Comment: @percusse Upvoting is personal so I'm not going to comment on that. Fixing... how? I fix the fixable but I cannot provide the content or context the OP had in mind, no-one can. Only the OP knows it. But what is your suggestion then? Answer any question regardless of its content, or lack thereof? I'm asking because I'm not sure I got it.

Comment: nevermind let's delete this pointless discussion. Clearly I'm not able to take you out of your personal view and show why this site used to be called a friendly place.

Comment: @percusse I'm trying to understand your point of view, that's why I'm asking you how you think this situation should be handled. I'm in the chatroom as well if you prefer talking there. I'm open to have my mind changed, but I want to know your arguments and how you want to change the situation first. I think that's reasonable.

Comment: @percusse Sure, but it's your choice. I just want to say that I don't think I fully disagree with you.

Comment: @Alenanno I wasn't really agreeing or disagreeing. I think you make several reasonable points but I would avoid terms like 'vampire'. I don't think that people who ask these questions are *predatory* but often just lost or desperate. But mostly I wanted to say that it is unfair to attribute motives to you without any justification. That is, even if you are entirely wrong (which I don't think), I still don't see any grounds for thinking that you are 'pompous'. Nor do I see good grounds for assuming that 'recent residents' are motivated by hostility or ill will.

Comment: Naturally, the fact that I fail to perceive such grounds will be attributed to my own hostility and pomposity. That's the effect of starting with the assumption that people are motivated by ill will: you can't see (or even imagine) any other possibilities. So, of course, you think that engaging people in discussion is pointless. You conclude that persuasion will inevitably fail and that the only option is to attack. This risks becoming a self-fulfilling prophecy: a great way to invoke hostility is to begin with the assumption that others are hostile. Thankfully, that hasn't happened (yet).

Comment: @cfr Yeah, maybe mentioning vampires changed how my opinion could be viewed. What I think is this: I like helping both on easy and hard tasks, also because something that seems easy is really hard (I know that by experience). What I don't like is when a question is just an image and that's it. I might still draw it because I like it, but there's nothing else to add? Some context? Some info? I always posted code when it was relevant, so if I could, why can't the others? Nobody has to start from scratch, I always browse the site for bits that I can reuse. I don't see this as unreasonable. [cont]

Comment: [cont] Maybe I'm wrong and maybe I'm contradicting myself, but although I might still answer a question that shows no effort, I don't like the implicit assumption it does which is "Do it for me". But if I'm wrong I would like to be explained why and also be told how this can be solved/handled.

Comment: @cfr  I would really encourage you to read carefully what is (was) written. Nobody called him pompous, but the behavior is pompous as I have elaborated countless times above and in the comments. If you cannot take criticism then at least don't divert it. I have definitely made my grounds at least thrice under the main site questions . If you would like to ignore the times I've engaged with you elsewhere fine but don't claim that I didn't provide evidence.

Comment: Besides it's not just you. I mean every user who is, in my point of view, abusing the text block comments Christian, Johannes, Larifari this or that. doesn't matter it is a collective change and I'm tired of my sentences being dissected without any comments on the gist of the matter. Similarly Papiro, Svend and others are abusing review system. I see no extensive discussions on their horrible reviewing but you don't mince words when I directly address this situation. I find this and all the discussion above pretty biased.

Comment: If some users get the kick out of clicking buttons and being correct all the time, I get it. But do it in your own sandbox. Stop commenting on the questions that you would not answer and don't feed the review trolls, if possible don't use review system at all. That is all there is. What is so difficult to understand this much?

Comment: @percusse What do you see to be "self-important" or pompous in my opinions or statements? I have shown multiple times that I can change it if given arguments that stand on their own merit. All you said is that you don't like some reviews and some comment blocks. Those are not arguments. Why does it bother you? If you really want to play by the things you said, then they're free to comment and review as much as you are free to answer questions you deem appropriate to answer to. This is their, mine sandbox as much as yours.

Comment: @Alenanno Because I can keep my distaste to myself instead of writing weird stuff under somebody else's question attempt. This is not a freedom issue you cannot claim ownership and way-of-behaving on a public domain. So that is the whole point I'm trying to convey over and over again but getting stuck in individual sentence shredding. Is there any way that I can make you stop commenting about **your own** behavior but how your behavior contributes to the distate of the whole site instead? Did you see MSE blog and comments under it? Can you see the similarities ?

Comment: @percusse So it is really the *making fun of*-part (for a lack of a better wording), that is discussed here. Not about the quality or non-quality of the post. I think for that special type of user interaction, a new topic (as hinted in an earlier comment to your answer) would be nice.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes but... I never saw anybody make fun of anybody in the question comments. In chat I have personally never seen any, but I'm speaking of what I've seen. If I saw somebody making fun of the OP I would flag the comment. But saying "Please add your preamble" or "Can you post a MWE?" are not what I consider "making fun of". This is considering you used that wording but maybe you meant something else.

Comment: @Johannes_B I did for review part. Nothing happened  so I don't see any point discussing further http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/reviewers-what-do-you-eat-for-breakfast

Comment: Alenanno, i know what @percusse means, as i was/am involved in that part. The thing is, that without the lack of personal interaction, we cannot judge *how* something was meant to sound. Sure, some of them were meant for pure amusement, some to warn other users to be careful, some were mere help requests for another site that currently has two regular helpers. I have been told, that my posts in german (and english) do sound very angry when reading. Sure, sometimes that might be true cause i had a bad day and instead of reacting to users i should take a break and let it be.

Comment: On the other hand, many answers lack a minimal working example and can be answered, making some assumptions (that may proove wrong), some cannot be answered. Asking for more information (mwe) is better than leaving the topic alone, ok some other might pick up on that, but maybe not. While going through the unanswered, i have seen questions containing an MWE and never got any feedback at all, no comment nothing.

Comment: @percusse While I agree with most of what you said in that post (that question looked fine *after* being edited, the first revision was unclear), but the closing mechanism has changed since then. Now questions are "on hold" and it changes to "closed" after a while. On hold means that it cannot be answered but it's the moment to edit/fix/improve. Now you might disagree with this, but you should hate the game, not the players. I'm not talking about specific closures, but in general. If as you said, some are blind-clicking "close/open", then I agree with you. Reviewing requires some thought.

Comment: @Johannes_B I agree, not all questions require a MWE, but it's often easier to start from something rather than nothing.

Comment: @Alenanno Yes, completely aggreeing here :-)

Comment: @percusse I did read carefully. I cannot reread what has now been deleted. I assume that you are sincere. I assume that you are well-intentioned. But since you cannot even imagine that 'recent residents' could be either, I will not discuss it further with you. I'm not interested in trying to persuade you differently and could not do so if I tried.

Comment: Is the objection here really to the system? This is not, after all, a public space in the real sense of that term. It is a private space made available to the public subject to various rules. Those rules are not altogether to my liking, but then I am not paying for the server space. Is the idea that TeX SE has some *second* set of rules, determined early on by a group of users, which govern how to play within the first set of rules? And 'recent residents' do not play by this *second* set? This would make sense, but you hardly need to attribute bad motives to people to explain that.

Comment: @Johannes_B I largely agree although there are references here to stuff I'm not aware of. I'm sure I also make mistakes and express frustration or irritation. But it does not follow from this that I am motivated by hostility or pomposity or whatever it is meant to be. What bothers me about this most is the assumptions being made about *why* people do things. Not only do I see no justification for those assumptions, I also think that, from a pragmatic point of view, those assumptions are counterproductive. They are a sure way to *encourage* hostility.

Comment: At this point there have been too many comments made, too many different discussion snippets, too many *I don't even know*. The real problem remains, all we see is written text, how we perceive this text corresponds to our own state. I am sure we could resolve the apparent issue in person within 5 minutes and have a nice chat afterwards. :-)

Comment: @cfr argument is simple we didn't have this problem before these users start reviewing and commenting, now we have it. Just for you I've included more examples in my answer also and previosly I've discussed your behavior under at least three questions trying to tell you that you are overreacting to new users. If you still can't see the justification it's not my problem. Same with other users, I don't even know why I'm continuing this discussion because apparently everyone else is happy. I'm slowly removing myself from the site so just have some patience and it's all going to be fine.

Comment: @percusse I think you're overreacting a bit. Besides we agreed (me and someone else) that reviews should be done with thought and not blindly clicking buttons. I've seen this problem in other sites as well, so it's not just TeX. But I agree with you on this, reviews should be done on the content. I never reviews on this site but in other sites I've done very few because it's time consuming. [continued]

Comment: @percusse [continued] On the comments we can discuss because I'm not sure if you don't like the wording of the comments or the comments themselves (regardless of the wording). Comment areas exist for asking for clarifications, so if you don't like asking the OP for clarifications or for improving the question, then you don't like not just this format but any format, because clarifications are asked in every forum created by mankind. So maybe it's the tone. Well, Meta exists for a reason: we can all agree on some standard comments *and* on guidelines on *when* to use them.

Comment: @Alenanno Please don't give me that idealistic definitions. I'm well aware of that. Current situation is far from asking for clarifications etc. I am really done providing examples. I've asked I don't know how many questions to you in the comments. I gave examples above to everyone. Still I get help page definitions of the purposes of commenting, closing, onhold/closed difference etc. I think I'm well capable of understanding what the site design is. So please let us stop it here. Because it is kind of weird having TeX.SX described to me.

Comment: @percusse I'm not explaining the site to you, I'm using those so it's easier to make my point. My point: the thing seems to be that you're against very basic features of this site, which I doubt to be the case, so the only thing that would make sense to me is that you're actually against the misuse of said features. Comments saying something when it's not warranted for example. Good. But if you're against these, then why not comment directly below the culprit stock comments pointing that out? That's an example.

Comment: @Alenanno I think you are missing a lot of history and context about what I have been doing over the last year. As I understand from your remark that you don't even know my former actions. Here is another text block that these users abuse, let's see how we arrived to that block http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/welcome-page-needs-more-welcoming . So let's not repeat a year worth of what I have done etc. if you want ask it in the chat room to others.

Comment: @percusse As I have explained several times in the past, I see no point in discussing this with you. You have made up your mind. [Of course, I make mistakes. But that is an entirely different point.] I responded here only because I saw the same pattern emerging. I thought it was just me, but now I understand that it is an entire class of users. I knew that if I responded here, I would be attacked but I could not simply watch somebody else being attacked in the same way without expressing some form of solidarity.

Comment: @Alenanno I also agree entirely that if users are blindly clicking buttons in review, that is a problem. I do sometimes review now they've changed the system a bit. I stopped for a while because by the time I'd read the post, it would no longer be there to review. Now they seem to hold it there so that you can take time to do it without other people reviewing it into oblivion in the meantime. I make an effort to do some reviews just because I think that if nobody who takes time does them, the only people reviewing will be users who just click. (I don't know if there are such users or not.)

Comment: @cfr No matter what kind of evidence I will put out there, you and that class of users will isolate yourself and only feel attacked. You asked for evidence it's there, you asked for a case study it's again up there. I didn't make up my mind on anything. Everything is documented in my answer and the linked discussions. As you can see from all those there is zero counter argument. Only sour comments such as *nobody is ill-intentioned*. I agree and also I add to that sentence *but intention is irrelevant*. Maybe you should once in a while question whether the solidarity is justified or not.

Comment: @percusse I absolutely disagree that intentions are irrelevant. But I'm not going to get drawn further into discussion about this with you.

Comment: @cfr A little 50 comments too late for that. Unless you have a concrete argument I don't care what the intentions of the users who are being intolerant to the new comers especially whom we didn't treat them as such when they arrived. You are one of them you should have known better.